# MySQL MASTER MASTER replication, adding a new Master with out downtime

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I have setup  master-master mysql replication in 2 different nodes. Suppose If i am going to add one more node, i.e 3rd master , do I need to have a exactly the same copy of the database in the new server as in the node-1 and node-2 ?

These are high traffic servers and will be keep on updating the database every seconds, so we would like to do it with out downtime. Is there any way to do this, with out downtime ?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.1.18, it is possible to use MySQL Cluster in multi-master replication, including circular replication between a number of MySQL Clusters.

Detailed explanation is explained here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-replication-multi-master.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

I know it is possible to add more nodes. But my concern is, would I be able to add it with out downtime ?

For adding the node we need to create the exact same database on the other server with same replica (please correct me if i am wrong). Since these two nodes are updating every second, we have to take down the traffic for few minutes inorder to create the same replica on the other server.   

I hope my concern is clear to you. Again thank you for spending your valuable time in replying to my query.

Comment: Please refer this post at server fault which can be useful to you http://serverfault.com/questions/332339/way-to-avoid-server-downtime-when-creating-master-slave-relationship